# Why does Pycharm debugger stopped working

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to debug my code in Pycharm but it is displaying as "pydev debugger: process 58159 is connecting" and simply giving the output.
Verified if there are any other breakpoints and deleted others. Still no luck. Also tried to debug the same code in different project which has even not worked.
The version I'm using is Pycharm 2019.3.3 (Community Edition). It was working fine till last night. Not sure what went wrong today.
I searched in Google but did not found the right answer. Please find the console output below.

```
/Users/so262757/PycharmProjects/sample/venv/bin/python "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 61273 --file /Users/so262757/PycharmProjects/sample/patternexample.py
pydev debugger: process 58159 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 193.6494.30)
1234
234
34
4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just to clarify: did you put *any* breakpoints? If you have no breakpoints at all, the debugger won't interrupt anywhere. Also is the breakpoint somewhere in the executed code i.e. is the breakpoint *reached*?

Comment: Ofcourse yes, added a breakpoint in the line 1 of my code. On clicking on Debug option, the above output is getting displayed without any further step overs.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.
All was working fine with pycharm 2019 then I updated to 2020 and updated debugger to the recommended

```
pip install pydevd-pycharm~=201.7223.92
```

This would not work at all.

The way I resolved it was to simply install the version of debugger below on the VM

```
 pip install pydevd-pycharm~=193.6911.25
```

I get a warning but all works perfectly. Hope it helps. Warning below which I just ignore

> Warning: wrong debugger version. Use pycharm-debugger.egg from PyCharm
>   installation folder Or execute: 'pip install
>   pydevd-pycharm~=201.7223.92' Expected: %s to exist. Traceback (most
>   recent call last):

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. The only way I could solve it without moving to an older version of Pycharm is to start a new project afresh (deleting the .idea folder).

If you don't want to do that then possibly moving back to Pycharm 2019.1.4 may help (worked for me).