# Opencv+arduino(face tracking) problems

Tags: python, opencv

This is a face tracker made with Opencv and Arduino, but something went wrong, this code will automatically stop after running.
My code is in this url:https://pastebin.com/Zeb2FMqc

```
def detectjob():
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.namedWindow("img", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        cv2.resizeWindow('img', 500, 500)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 5)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            arr = {y: y + h, x: x + w}
            xx = int(x + (x + h)) / 2
            print(xx)
            yy = int(y + (y + w)) / 2
            print(yy)
            data = "X{0:f}Y{0:f}".format(xx, yy) + 'c'
            print(data)
            arduino.write(data.encode())
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: "this code will automatically stop after running". Could you please add more information about your issue? I can not understand what your issue.

Comment: About your code, i understood your flow code. You track the face on your laptop and then push the data down to arduino via serial. This issue can be handle by debugging. Please try to debug.

Comment: It is my resuit after debugged :

Comment: D:\python\python.exe "D:\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 5491 --file "D:/science eye tracking/science - mulit.py"
Connected to pydev debugger (build 203.7148.72)
Connection to arduino...

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339606/why-does-pycharm-debugger-stopped-working

Comment: We have already tried for several weeks, but our code just stop itself, and we consider that it might be the multiprocessing is stopping which means it pops out the loop.

Comment: I tried to use original ide ,and this problem was solved

Comment: "original ide", what do you mean??

Comment: It mean “Python idle”

Comment: I have also tried to figure out your problem and I realize that this problem comes from the debug feature of pycharm. Try many other IDEs such as Spyder, visual studio, eclipse, ... or simply VS code.

Comment: Ok.Thanks,Bro!